# Android Scringo Error

Tags: android, chat

I followed the steps which in Scringo webiste for adding Scringo to my project which is at this link:
http://dev.scringo.com/downloads.php
at installition, then choosing Android platform.
The problem is always when I run my application it always show that null pointer exception in log cat:

```
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{its.center/its.center.main.Main}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at com.scringo.general.ScringoResources.getResourceId(ScringoResources.java:13)
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at com.scringo.panel.ScringoPulley.init(ScringoPulley.java:40)
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at com.scringo.panel.ScringoPulley.<init>(ScringoPulley.java:35)
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at com.scringo.controller.ScringoController.initPanel(ScringoController.java:64)
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at com.scringo.Scringo.internalInit(Scringo.java:30)
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at com.scringo.Scringo.init(Scringo.java:24)
11-07 13:12:05.093: E/AndroidRuntime(16262):    at its.center.main.Main.onCreate(Main.java:45)
```

and when I trace that Null pointer exception it goes at this line in the java code:

```
Scringo.init(this);
```

Anyone can help in solving this error?

Addition questions:
Does anyone tried Scringo before on Android, and does it worked well?

Comment: declare a global variable `Context context = this;` then use `Scringo.init(this);`

Answer (score 2):

Did you place the scringo.properties file in the assets folder?